# Start to Proof of bernoulli polynomials and sums

Tags: real-analysis, combinatorics, complex-analysis

I need help starting this proof: 
For all integers k,l,m>=0 and not all equal to 0,
(3.7)
[image: equation3.7]
It says that that comparing the above equation (3.7) with the one discussed earlier in the paper(3.6) (shown below) clearly shows that 3.6 is the base case in an induction proof of 3.7, where l=0., and only the order of summation of the third sum in 3.7 needs to be reversed.

(3.6)
[image: equation3.6]
Could someone show me how to do this proof? I dont understand it at all.